# The WS-Management service cannot find the certificate that was requested

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-server, winrm

Server1 sends WinRM Get request -

[image]

Server2 has been listening -

[image]
I guarantee that CertificateThumbprint and IP addresses in both servers match (Sorry part of IP addresses and CertificateThumbprint have to be removed since I am not allowed to publish all here).
I don't know why WinRM still has the error "The WS-Management service cannot find the certificate that was requested" presented.

Comment: Did you solve this issue Don, and if yes, how?

Comment: @Richard, no.  I did not.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution to this problem. You must create a CSR, from the CSR you use digicert utility to create the certificate. That you import, and export again with the private key. Import that in the Certificate store and use winrm create to create the listener.

All found in my [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41890240/winrm-using-https-transport-cannot-create-a-winrm-listener-on-https-because-thi/41940396#41940396).

Answer (score 0):

There are probably many reasons for this error.  In my case we were using the existing IIS SSL cert which was working for WinRM on some machines but not others.  The difference was the certificate was marked as exportable on the ones that worked.

Try re-importing the certificate and making sure it is marked as exportable.

Export/Import certificates:
https://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/pfx-import-export-iis-7.htm

Answer (score 0):

Below steps worked for me .

1. Exportable certificate be imported to "Certificates (Local Computer)\Personal"
2. Run the script below (Ref :https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/windows_setup.html#winrm-setup )

---

```
$selector_set = @{
    Address = "*"
    Transport = "HTTPS"
}
$value_set = @{
    CertificateThumbprint = "E6CDAA82EEAF2ECE8546E05DB7F3E01AA47D76CE"
}

New-WSManInstance -ResourceURI "winrm/config/Listener" -SelectorSet $selector_set -ValueSet $value_set
```