# WinRm - Cannot create a WinRM listener on HTTPS due to incorrect SSL certificate

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, winrm, certreq

I want to use WinRM with https transport. I've bought a Comodo certificate (the error states I cannot use a self-signed certificate) with the Subject matching my FQDN (Full computer name in System) of my Windows 10 computer (not domain joined):

```
CN = my.domain.net 
OU = PositiveSSL 
OU = Domain Control Validated
```

When trying to create a https listener with the following command:

> WinRm quickconfig -transport:https

I get the error message:

> Error number:  -2144108267 0x80338115
> Cannot create a WinRM listener on HTTPS because this machine does not have an appropriate certificate. To be used for SSL, a certificate must have a CN matching the hostname, be appropriate for Server Authentication, and not be expired, revoked, or self-signed.

I've installed (doubleclick the *.crt file) the certificate in several stores (local machine / personal and Trusted Root Certification Authorities) but WinRM fails to create the https listener. The http listener is working OK.

Some extra info: When using certreq to try to install the `*.cer` certificate, I get the error:

> Element not found. 0x80070490 (WIN32: 1168 ERROR_NOT_FOUND)

How do I get WinRM working with https?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how I solved this issue:

- create a SSL CSR using DigiCert Certificate Utility for Windows from digicert.com
- use the generate CSR to request a certificate. I used versio.nl but I'll guess there are a lot of CA's out there
- Install the certificate by double clicking it
- go to the certificate manager for user
- rightclick the certificate (it should me in the personal store) and export it
  - follow the wizard and be sure to export the private key
- install the newly exported certificate (mark the key as exportable and include all extended properties) in the local computer certificate store

Open an console (cmd) with administrator privilidges and type:

> winrm create winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTPS 
>   @{Hostname="server.fqdn";CertificateThumbprint="YOURCERTIFICATETHUMPPRINT"}

This worked for me. Some things to check if it is not working:

1. is the certificate still valid (check the date range)
2. check if the certificate property 'Subject" has a CN value with the FQDN of your computer
3. check if the listener is installed (winrm e winrm/config/listener)

I took me a lot of hours to figure this out. I hope it will help some of you out there.

Comment: Your command didnt work for me with error : "Error: Invalid use of command line."
Instead i used :
`$cert = Get-ChildItem -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\MyCertThumbprint` (can use tab)
Then
`New-Item -Path WSMan:\LocalHost\Listener -Transport HTTPS -Address * -CertificateThumbPrint $Cert.Thumbprint –Force`

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue - the answer from RHAD was partially helpful, but I needed to use an entirely internally generated CA.

The problem was caused by the Key algorithm I had chosen.  Using the same configuration, only changing the key it works:

Failed key: elliptic curve cryptography with the brainpoolP512t1 curve (in the certificate this showed as: Public Key Algorithm: id-ecPublicKey / ASN1 OID: brainpoolP512t1 )

Successful key: an RSA key: (in the certificate: RSA Public-Key: (4096 bit))

Hopefully this helps others with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the above - pointed me in the right direction.

My Certificate did not have the key bundled with it - running the following created a certificate that could then be installed in the usual manner and which WinRM accepted:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out "merged_server_cert.txt" -inkey "my_server.key" -in "merged_server&intermediate_cerificates.txt"
```

Note the server certificate must have the server certificate and any intermediates included in it one after the other.

Once I'd done the above the `WinRm quickconfig -transport:https` command worked as normal :)